# Regex with digits characters and understrike

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello i want create regex code with minimum 3 characters or 3 digits and optional understike

I expecting regex to check strings like this

```
D3D //true
FFF //true
344 //true
SFD_334 //true
D8G7F9 //true
_SSS_333 //false
_HHF888 //false
A98FFF_ //false
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: This is not 3 Char or 3 digits. OR. SFD_334

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!_)[\dA-Z_]+(?<!_)$
```

```js
const strings = [
  'D3D', //true
  'FFF', //true
  '344', //true
  'SFD_334', //true
  'D8G7F9', //true
  '_SSS_333', //false
  '_HHF888', //false
  'A98FFF_', //false
]

for (const string of strings) {
  console.log(string, string.match(/^(?!_)[\dA-Z_]+(?<!_)$/) ? 'true' : 'false')
}
```